# Why does Resources.Load <Sprite> return null?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My project has multiple sprites located in Assets\Sprites which I want to load using C# script.

I have tested this:

```
Sprite myFruit = Resources.Load <Sprite> ("Graphics_3");
```

But `myFruit` is still null.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`Resources.Load` will search for a directory in `Assets/Resources`.

If you want to put it to `Sprites` directory then put it inside `Resources` (ex. `Assets/Resources/Sprites`).

Then you can just load it like this:

```
Sprite myFruit = Resources.Load <Sprite> ("Sprites/Graphics_3");
```

Also make sure that you've set your image type to Sprite in the inspector.

If you want to load multiple sprites, use this:

```
Sprite[] myFruit = Resources.LoadAll <Sprite> ("Sprites/Graphics_3");
```

See [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/585927/unity-43-a-problem-with-loading-the-multiple-sprit.html) for more details.

Comment: If I load a single sprite, it worked! But I test with multiple sprite, It did't work exaccly, and the scenes was paused!!

Comment: I've editted my answer, perhaps that's what you want

Comment: Keep in mind that `Resources.Load()` will not only search in `Assets/Resources`, but in any directory named `Resources` under any other directory, e.g. `Assets/Sprites/Resources`, `Assets/Foobar/Plugin/Resources`, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Searched a lot, but this answer worked like a charm.

Comment: ..and this answer saved somebody else in 2019 :) Thanks a lot dude

Answer (score 3):

Place `awesome.png` in `Assets/Resources/` (you can have subfolders), and use:

```
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = 
    Resources.Load<Sprite>("awesome");  // No file extension.
```

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html

There's also [LoadAll](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAll.html) that *"Loads all assets in a folder or file at path in a Resources folder."*

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but, if it still does not work by just loading the resources, then we have to add the texture as well. I did it in this way.

```
Texture2D texture = Resources.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/imageName");
Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), Vector2.zero);
btnImage.image.sprite = sprite;
```

Answer (score 1):

I required a different solution for this problem. When i carefully inspected my sprite, I saw the dropdown "Sprite Mode" was empty (even though that shouldn't be even possible I think).
Once I selected single and applied the changes, the problem went away.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please enrich your answer by providing some code!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter the full path for the asset. In this case, try using the path "Sprites/Graphics_3".

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sprite sp = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite> ("Sprites/AI-Avtar") [2] as Sprite;
```

Comment: as Sprite would be redundant here because you already loading by type: (LoadAll<Sprite>)

Answer (score 0):

Resources.Load are searching in the directory  "Assets/Resources"
That's why you need to do

```
_sprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(spritesPath);
```

or

```
_sprites = Resources.Load<Sprite>(spritesPath);
```

with spritesPath as relative path.
If you need to load all from folder "Assets/Resources/Sprites", you need to write only "Sprites".

after this you can just do the following:

```
var sprite = sprites[0];
```

or

```
var sprite = _sprites.Where(a => a.name == "Sprite_Name_Needed").First();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unity's scripting reference doesn't says that you need write  `<Sprite>` right after `Load`. So I had problem with loading sprites, although my sprite was in Resources directory.

Answer (score 0):

I just used Resources.Load to load my sprite and found the result is Texture2D. So I Use Sprite.Create to create a new sprite with Textur2D to fix this problem.

Comment: You can change image type to be Sprite in import settings and you wont need to create a new one every time