# C# Loading Sprites in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

These expressions both return a null reference:

```
Resources.Load("poo") as Sprite

Resources.Load<Sprite>("poo")
```

And I cannot for the life of me figure out why.
The file "poo.png" is definitely in the "Resources" folder.
The expression:

```
Resources.Load("poo")
```

...returns a Texture2D object

Is there some other way to load a Sprite in Unity?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629874/unity-resources-loadsprite-vs-as-sprite tl;dr: use `Resource.Load<Sprite>()` instead of `Resource.load() as Sprite`

Comment: I had already read and tried that. It didn't make any difference. But i updated this question to include that approach as well.

Comment: don't worry, I opened a new question

Comment: Actually, re-open this one. someone closed the new one.

Comment: Why didn't the solution at the duplicate work?

Comment: Because it returned a null reference, exactly as is now stated in the edited version of this question.

Comment: Sounds like "poo" doesn't exist, or for some reason it cannot be converted to a sprite.

Comment: Resources.Load("poo") returns a Texture2D, ergo, poo exists.

Comment: Then it cannot be cast to a sprite.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28636559/102937) explains that precisely.

Comment: that answer states that "Resources.Load<Sprite>" fixes the problem, which it clearly does not in this case. Also the O.P did not even accept the validity of that answer.

Comment: You're missing the point.  Whatever you're trying to load as a sprite cannot be so loaded.

Comment: Which files can be loaded as a sprite?

Comment: That's a good question.  If you amend this question to that effect, I'll reopen.

Comment: Oh... turns out you have to 'set' it to sprite in the property inspector. It's answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977986/load-sprite-from-asset-sprites Yeah, I guess you can close this question now. It would be good if the question was rewriten as "Q:Why doesn't Resources.Load<sprite> work? A:Because you have to set the file to sprite in the property inspector first!"

Comment: I fixed the title in that question.  Bad question titles are a real problem here; people usually put their Google Search in the title. >_<

Comment: The problem is that people don't know what the problem is when they need to ask for help. If they already knew what was the problem then they could just look it up in the manual.